# My car won't crank

Tags: ford, ignition, no-crank-no-start

I started my car the other day and turned the car off.

When I tried starting it back up it wouldn't crank.

I took the key out and my dashboard gauges would stay on.

I can start it up by the solenoid.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Make Model And Year please...

Comment: as well, a more detailed description would be helpful.  simple statements of facts and what you are experiencing under different circumstances.

Comment: I edited your question.  If you can go back and edit it and put in more statements regarding what you are experiencing people will flow to the question because of the provided data.  Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Two key observations (no pun intended):

- jumping the solenoid starts the engine
- dashboard lights stay on even with the key out

This tells me that the ignition circuitry is not following the key position in the ignition barrel. This could be due to a bad ignition switch or break in the associated wiring.

Comment: My thinking too... But could also be a burnt fusible link... Both happened to me in a fox body stang.... Same symptoms different timing